# Scraping incidents in a table in a website

Tags: python-3.x, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract a table into pandas from a website that is automatically updated on a regular basis. I tried:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website = 'http://www.dallasfirerescue.com/active_incidents.html'
req = Request(website)
abc = urlopen(req)
raw = abc.read().decode("utf-8") 
page = raw.replace('<!-->', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")
print (table)
```

It gives me None

Answer (score 0):

Your link didn't work for me, but here is a great example of how to download data from an HTML table into Python.

```
# import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
page = requests.get("https://www.aucklandairport.co.nz/flights").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tbody = soup.find('tbody')
rows = tbody.findAll('tr',{'class':'flight-toggle'}) #find tr whose class = flight-toggle
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td',class_=lambda x: x != 'logo') # find td whose class!=logo (exclude the first td)
    dv0 = cols[0].find('div').findAll('div') #flight, carrier, origin under second td
    flight, carrier, origin = [c.text.strip() for c in dv0]
    dv1 = cols[1].find('div').findAll('div') #date, schedule under third td
    date, scheduled = [c.text.strip() for c in dv1]
    dv2 = cols[2].find('div').findAll('div') #estimated, statusunder fouth td
    estimated, status = [c.text.strip() for c in dv2[1:]] # exclude the first div 
    print(flight, carrier, origin, date, scheduled, estimated, status)
```

See the links below for more info.

http://srome.github.io/Parsing-HTML-Tables-in-Python-with-BeautifulSoup-and-pandas/

https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/web-scraping-with-pandas-and-beautifulsoup/

Answer (score 0):

The content of that page is generated dynamically. You can't grab the response by making `http request`. You need to use any browser simulator instead. Here is how you can achieve that. I used `selenium` in this case:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.dallasfirerescue.com/active_incidents.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
table = soup.find(class_="CSVTable")
for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
    data = [item.text.strip() for item in tr.find_all("td")]
    print(data)
driver.quit()
```

When you execute the above script, the data from the table of that webpage will be available in your grip.

Comment: That is a fantastic solution! Can I also maintain the table-like nature of the data, rather than getting a text style output?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've already edited the code. Let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: I am trying to obtain a data frame format. Additionally, I tried to include a timestamp next to what I obtain with your code that shows the date of the entry. I tried adding below but failed to create the dataframe.
    datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%T')